# Create method stopped working

Tags: laravel, controller

I have this simple code

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->Validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|min:3|max:20',
        'age' => 'required|integer|between:18,99',
        'height' => 'required|integer|between:120,230',
        'weight' => 'required|integer|between:30,150',
        'region' => 'required|integer',
        'city' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required|integer'
    ]);
    Person::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'age' => $request->age,
        'height' => $request->height,
        'weight' => $request->weight,
        'city_id' => $request->city,
        'region_id' => $request->region,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
    ]);
}
```

This code stop working but it doesn't show error. I have only white page. This code has worked before. And ne record doesn't create. What happend?
@edit
Now it works but... In phpmyadmin everything is ok. New records are added coccectly but tinker show my only one record which I added manually in phpmyadmin. If I try choose the lastest record added by me:

```
$latest = Person::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->latest()->first();
```

It show me this single element which I created in phpmyadmin. What's wrong?

Comment: You are not returning anything. Probably, that's why it shows a white page.

Comment: I know but new record doesn't create. This is my problem.

Comment: Could you show your create method?

Comment: Before Create Query give exit(); and try to echo something to check May your code reachs till there or not.

Comment: I show my create metod above.

Comment: Model::create is a standard method on an Eloquent model. If the record is not being created, its likely an issue with the properties on the model matching to the table columns or table name. Can you show use code for the model?

Comment: Yes I can see your create code. echo something after validation code complete. Just to check your page stopped in validation part itself

Comment: I don't know how i can show code on the comment (I'm newbie on this website)

Comment: I tryed add dd($request->all()); on the end of my code and it works.

Comment: `$this->Validate($request` here `$request` or `$request->all()`?

Comment: only $request. $request->all() I used in order to display data from $request. It was only test. How I can show code in comment?

Comment: Edit your question with the updated results. Much easier to read there.

Comment: Your code may be failing after the validate, ensure you pass all those conditions on the validate , probably try having a print variable after the validation to see if variables are received from the request.

Comment: OK. It works but I check it in tinker. In phpmadmin everything is ok. But when I try choose the latest element added by me $latest = AdvWomen::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->latest()->first(); It show me only one element which I added manually in phpmyadmin. Why?

Comment: Hi @MrBelongsTo first of check database column create_at exist or not because The latest and oldest methods allow you to easily order results by date.By default, result will be ordered by the created_at column.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller :

```
   public function store(Request $request)
   {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|min:3|max:20',
        'age' => 'required|integer|between:18,99',
        'height' => 'required|integer|between:120,230',
        'weight' => 'required|integer|between:30,150',
        'region' => 'required|integer',
        'city' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required|integer'
    ]);

    Person::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'age' => $request->age,
        'height' => $request->height,
        'weight' => $request->weight,
        'city_id' => $request->city,
        'region_id' => $request->region,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
    ]);
    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Person Created');

}
```

in your blade view :

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
  @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <p class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">{{ $error }}
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </p>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: I think you missed the most important part: going back with the errors if validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

Replace store as below:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
      $this->Validate($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|min:3|max:20',
        'age' => 'required|integer|between:18,99',
        'height' => 'required|integer|between:120,230',
        'weight' => 'required|integer|between:30,150',
        'region' => 'required|integer',
        'city' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required|integer'
    ]);
    $person= new Person();
    $person->username= $request['username'];
    $person->age = $request['age'];
    $person->height = $request['height'];
    $person->weight = $request['weight'];
    $person->region = $request['region'];
    $person->city = $request['city'];
    $person->phone = $request['phone'];
    $person->save();

}
```

Comment: Please explain the reasoning behind your answer.